# How to add "get inserted id value" into label using 3 ".cs" in my code using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been learning this through youtube and would like to figure how SAP show our created id in a label, yet I have read so many guide to get the value but I keep ending in 0. Thus, I am sending my code here and please help where should I create the object and summon the value.

My BLL

```
class customerBLL
{
    public int CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Add1 { get; set; }
    public string Add2 { get; set; }
    public string Add3 { get; set; }
    public string PIC { get; set; }
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress{ get; set; }
    public string PriceGroup { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public int AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedTime { get; set; }
    public string updateId { get; set; }
}
```

My DAL

```
public bool Insert(customerBLL c)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(orderan);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO CustomerTb(CompanyName, Add1, Add2,   Add3, PIC, Phone1, Phone2, Fax, EmailAddress, PriceGroup, Remarks, AddedBy, AddedTime) " +  
                     "VALUES (@CompanyName, @Add1, @Add2, @Add3, @PIC, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Fax, @EmailAddress, @PriceGroup, @Remarks, @AddedBy, @AddedTime); " + 
                     "SET @newPK = SCOPE_IDENTITY;";
                
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", c.CompanyName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add1", c.Add1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add2", c.Add2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add3", c.Add3);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PIC", c.PIC);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone1", c.Phone1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone2", c.Phone2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fax", c.Fax);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", c.EmailAddress);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriceGroup", c.PriceGroup);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", c.Remarks);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddedBy", c.AddedBy);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddedTime", c.AddedTime);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(c.updateId, "@newPK");

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        con.Open();
                                
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rows > 0)
        {
            isSuccess = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

This is the UI code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c.CompanyName = textBox1.Text;
    c.Add1 = textBox2.Text;
    c.Add2 = textBox3.Text;
    c.Add3 = textBox4.Text;
    c.PIC = textBox5.Text;
    c.Phone1 = textBox6.Text;
    c.Phone2 = textBox7.Text;
    c.Fax = textBox8.Text;
    c.EmailAddress = textBox9.Text;
    c.PriceGroup = textBox10.Text;
    c.Remarks = textBox11.Text;
    c.AddedBy = 1;
    c.AddedTime = DateTime.Now;
            
    bool success = cdal.Insert(c);

    string orderan = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["orderan"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(orderan);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
    if (success == true)
    {
        label12.Text = c.updateId.ToString() +" "+ "succesfully created";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to add");
    }    
}
```

I understand the `c.updateId` haven't get any value yet, this is disturbing to me that no matter I put the

```
Dim updateId As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

in the DAL or in the UI, which I added new connection configuration.

I couldn't get the value. The label always shows "0 successfully created".

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(c.updateId, "@newPK");` has the parameter as the second argument, and the value as the first argument. That doesn't look right to me... (I'd also avoid using `AddWithValue`, personally, but that's a different matter...)

Comment: But even if you have them the right way round, executing the SQL won't modify `c.updateId`. You'd need to create an output parameter and then extract the value from it afterwards.

Comment: As a note: you could make your question much simpler to understand by using a tiny console application instead of a UI, and just have a table with two columns - one generated and one provided by the insert statement.

Comment: Try declaring *@newPk* as an output parameter:
```var parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@newPk", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "YourIdColumnName");
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

After ExecuteNonQuery you should be able to receive the id: `int id = (int)parameter.Value;`

Comment: Hi Jon, advice taken. thank you

Comment: HI Michael, i actually not understand what you aretalking about. since i am really green about this. just trying to cope with this equal this and this equal that at this moment.
however, Karen answered my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example which in the operation to add a new record sets the returning `primary key` from the INSERT statement to the `Id property` of the Employee.

Yes, the code does not match your code but the idea is to show one possible `how to` for inserting a record and obtaining the new key.

GitHub [source code](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/tree/Version1/SqlServerInsertRecord)

[image]

I'm using an existing database with Employee model.

```
using System;

namespace SqlServerInsertRecord.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime? HiredDate { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Class which in this case contains only a method for adding a new record. The return type, named value tuple is used in the caller to determine if the operation was successful and if an exception is thrown you have access to the exception.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SqlServerInsertRecord.Models;

namespace SqlServerInsertRecord.Classes
{
    public class Operations
    {
        private static string _connectionString =
            "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ForumExample;Integrated Security=True";

        public static (bool success, Exception exception) Insert(Employee employee)
        {
            using (var cn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = _connectionString })
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn })
                {
                    
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.employee (FirstName, LastName, HiredDate) " +
                                      "VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @HiredDate);" +
                                      "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = employee.FirstName;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = employee.LastName;
                    
                    if (employee.HiredDate.HasValue)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HiredDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = employee.HiredDate.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HiredDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        cn.Open();

                        employee.Id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                        return (true, null);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return (false, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Form code** to insert a record with mocked data

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee() {FirstName = "Karen", LastName = "Payne", HiredDate = DateTime.Now};

    /*
     * If needed use exception returned from 
     */
    var (success, exception) = Operations.Insert(employee);
    label1.Text = success ? $"New id: {employee.Id}" : "Failed";
}
```

Comment: Hi Karen, very thankful for your guidance. successfully done!